# MySQL insert where not exists / if not exists

Tags: mysql, insert

I have tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `surfed_site` (user, site)
VALUES ('123', '456')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT site FROM `surfed_site` WHERE site=456)
```

But I keep getting a MySQL error:

**1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT site FROM `surfed_site` WHERE site=456)' at line 3**

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, would anybody be able to guide me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`INSERT` statements support two<sup>1</sup> syntaxes: one that uses `VALUES`, and one that uses a query.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) You can't combine them, and only the query syntax supports `WHERE` clauses. So:

```
INSERT INTO `surfed_site` (user, site)
SELECT '123', '456' FROM (SELECT 1) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT site FROM `surfed_site` WHERE site=456)
```

---

1. Actually *three* syntaxes; you can also use `SET`. If you're only inserting one record, this one is functionally equivalent to `VALUES`, but arguably more readable.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me, I am getting the error message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT site FROM `surfed_site` WHERE site=456)' at line 3

Comment: @LiamGordon: Oh, sorry. I've edited my answer to give what's *hopefully* a fixed version -- not tested. (Sorry, if nothing else I should have indicated that I hadn't tested what I posted.)