# SQL Insert Ignore Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am very sorry yes I know this has been asked before but when I look at the post it looks like I am doing everything right yet it isn't working.

So I want to make a sql insert only if that $domain does not exist in the database, I don't mind if multiple domains have the same IP.

Here is my current sql query which doesn't add any domains and IPs to the database.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO domains (domain, ip) VALUES ('$domain', '$ip') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM domains where domain='$domain')");
```

Comment: if you don't mind if multiple domains have the same ip, then...  what's the problem?  just insert

Comment: Because I want to store multiple domains on same IP but not multiple domains. For example one shared hosting server with the IP 1.1.1.1 might have 3 domains running on it. But I don't want the same IP for the same domain in the DB

Comment: OK, so make a unique index on `domain`, and `INSERT IGNORE INTO domains...`.  also by the way you are way open to sql injection, which means a bored nerd could delete your entire database; `mysql_query` is super deprecated and you should either use PDO or mysqli with bound parameters

Comment: I see, I will fix the sqli. Also how would I make the Insert Ignore statement?

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO domains (domain, ip) VALUES (:domain, :ip)`.  there's also a `REPLACE` and a handful of other alternatives, depending on what you want to happen when there's a duplicate domain.

Comment: @Eevee ok with INSERT IGNORE INTO domains (domain, ip) VALUES (:domain, :ip) the lines are now being added to the DB. 

But if I insert the same duplicate values again they will get added to the DB instead of being ignored

Comment: you need to create a unique index on `domain`.  `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX domains_domain ON domains (domain);` -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a long solution but good for columns that don't have UNIQUE attribute.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (your_column)
SELECT 'your_value' FROM (SELECT 1) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT your_same_column
        FROM you_same_table
        WHERE your_same_column = 'your_same_value'
    );
```

Got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463913/mysql-insert-where-not-exists-if-not-exists)

But if your column in question has a UNIQUE attribute, then you could just do this short method.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO your_table(your_column) VALUES('your_value');
```

Comment: `FROM DUAL` should work just as well, if you need a `FROM` clause at all.  also that `NOT EXISTS` will take a full table scan if you don't have an index...  and if you have an index you don't need to do it  :)

Comment: Eevee I am not sure how to set an Index I researched the link you said and tried making the following command which is even better if it worked but it adds duplicates. mysql_query("REPLACE INTO domains (domain, ip) VALUES ('$domain', '$ip')"); . 

TY Craftein, currently trying this out

Comment: i gave you the query to create a unique index as a comment on your question; just paste that into a mysql client.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to apply `SELECT` to domain

```
INSERT INTO domains (domain, ip)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ('$domain', '$ip')) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM domains where domain='$domain'
);
```

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for reply just tried that and not working.

Comment: Ok just tried mysql_query("INSERT INTO domains (domain, ip) 
             VALUES ('$domain', '$ip')

             SELECT domain, ip FROM domains

             WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                 SELECT null FROM domains where domain='$domain'
             )");

and not working

Comment: you can't use `VALUES` and `SELECT` at the same time; that doesn't make any sense.  they're different ways of specifying what rows to insert.

Comment: i don't entirely understand what you're trying to do here; do you want to only avoid duplicated _pairs_ of `(domain, ip)`?  or only one ip per domain at all?

Comment: you could just `SELECT :domain, :ip`; no need to wrap it in a subquery.  also `WHERE :domain NOT IN (SELECT domain FROM domains)` seems more natural and possibly easier to optimize.  but really this should just be done with a unique index

Comment: What's a unique index? Thank you for the help Eevee

Comment: that's a pretty basic database concept; you might want to step back and read a little deeper on database design.  for mysql, explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html